# Wanted but not invoked. Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. Kinesis.Worker AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, mocking, mockito, amazon-kinesis

I have tried several things to solve this exception. This is an existent test in the application that I had never worked.

```
 import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisClientLibConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TeamEventStreamWorkerTest {
    @Mock
    Worker worker;

    @Mock
    KinesisClientLibConfiguration kinesisClientLibConfiguration;

    @Test
    void onApplicationEvent() throws InterruptedException {
        TeamEventStreamWorker teamEventStreamWorker = new TeamEventStreamWorker(null, null, null, kinesisClientLibConfiguration, null) {
            Worker createDynamoDbStreamsWorker() {
                return worker;
            }
        };

        doNothing().when(worker).run();

        teamEventStreamWorker.onApplicationEvent(null);

        // Wait to make sure worker run is called by the async mechanism
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        verify(worker).run();

    }
}
```

I know the problem is with ***worker.run()*** method. worker and kinesis object are objects for the library of Kinesis from amazon.

Note: The most strange thing is when I test in my local machine(IntelliJ) works perfect, but when I do a push and the Jenkins job starts to try, always returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Exception message you've received tells that `worker.run()` method was never called within your test. You could changes the set-up of increase sleeping time. The test passes as soon as `worker.run()` is called at least once.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I have tried to increase sleeping time to 5 seconds and the error is the same.

Comment: Then you need to debug step by step to find out why the method is not called.

Comment: Or rather than using sleep, use a library called Awaitility to not do unnecessary sleeping.